# Stuck with connection timed out on trying to get and parse stock price

Tags: java, url, dom4j

Am trying to get the latest stock price of a stock. The URL am using as an example is

`String stockURL=http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=ADSL`.

Am able to open this link in my browser. I have written the following code in order to parse the document which I get after executing the URL.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(stockUrl);
        GettingCurrentStockPrice gettingCurrentStockPrice = new GettingCurrentStockPrice();
        gettingCurrentStockPrice.readDoc(gettingCurrentStockPrice
                .parse(url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Encountered MalformedURLException:" + e);

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Encountered DocumentException:" + e);
    }

}

private Document parse(URL url) throws DocumentException {
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read(url);
    return document;
}

private void readDoc(Document document) {
    Element root = document.getRootElement();

    // iterate through child elements of root
    for (Iterator<Element> i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Element element = (Element) i.next();
        System.out.println(element);
    }

    for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator("company data"); i.hasNext();) {
        Element compName = (Element) i.next();
        System.out.println("compName-->" + compName);
    }

}
```

On running the program, am ending with,

`Encountered DocumentException:org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection timed out: connect Nested exception: Connection timed out: connect`.

Why is it unable to open the URL given?

**Update:** The problem comes in `parse()` line `render.read(url);`.

Comment: Are you using proxy to execute this

Comment: No. Am able to open it normally. Even if it was proxy, how would it affect?

Comment: If you use proxy you have to add proxy code before calling any URL. Else it will give same error

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035973/connect-to-a-site-using-proxy-code-in-java

Comment: Nope. Am not using any. Am able to open the url as it is.

Comment: I am also stuck with the same situation. Hope someone answers :(